# file.path function in R

Tags: r

I am learning function called `file.path()` in `R`. I am wondering whether this command will change the working directory just like `setwd()` or simply give `R` the path of the file and change the workspace only? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see the help by typing `?file.path`. To get the current directory, type `getwd()`. So try `file.path` and type `getwd()` to see whether it has an effect on the current directory.

Answer (score 6):

`file.path()` is just a convenient way of making a file path (it won't actually do any navigation at all)

e.g. if I want "C:\Users\John\Documents"

`file.path("C:", "Users", "John", "Documents", fsep="/")`

You could then pass that to `setwd()` like so

```
path <- file.path("C:", "Users", "John", "Documents", fsep="\\")
setwd(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

`file.path()` is used to create reproducible code that can be run on other operating systems.

i.e. mac and windows use different directory separators

Therefore, reducing the headache for the person you give your script to with a different OS