# Printing row and column number of each file in a folder

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, fread

I trying to read the number of rows and columns in several csv files inside a folder.

My code read all files but showed 0 row and 0 column.

```
files_map <- "C:/Users/Windows 10/Desktop/dados/planilhas LLS" 
files <- list.files(full.names = F)

library(data.table)

output <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(files, function(file) {
    dt <- data.table::fread(paste(files_map, file, sep = " "))
    list("number_of_cols" = ncol(dt), "number_of_rows" = nrow(dt), "name_of_file" = file)}))
```

How could I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the files aren’t empty?

Comment: Yes. The files have around 16000 lines and 20 columns.

Comment: There is a syntax error.  You have used `files` instead of `file` inside the `fread`? i..e i would have used `files <- list.files(path = ""C:/Users/Windows 10/Desktop", "pattern = "planilhas LLS", full.names = TRUE); and then you don't need the `paste` inside

Comment: Sorry. I write wrong. The code was corrected now.

Comment: Do you have working directory as `"C:/Users/Windows 10/Desktop/dados"`, then you may just need `files <- list.files(,"pattern = "planilhas LLS", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: Not work. Now the `files` vector are empty.

Comment: what about earlier, when you use `list.files(full.names = FALSE)`.  Can you show one of the values from the list.files output

Comment: I use `list.files(full.names = FALSE)` to not show all address of the file, just the name of the file.

Comment: @WilsonSouza you are not even showing the contents of the list.files.  So, it is not clear why it is not working

Comment: I've provided the answer, but really though you can just debug this yourself, it should be pretty easy. Set ``file=files[1]`` and then step through each part of the ``lapply`` function to find out where it's going wrong.

Comment: Instead of `paste(files_map, file, sep = " ")` use `sep="/"` or, even better, [`file.path`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html), see also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884777/8245406).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test on my computer, slightly changing your files and this produces a correct output. You need to change `paste` to `paste0` because you don't want spaces in your filenames, and then add a trailing `/`.

```
library(data.table)

setwd("Desktop/")

## make up some random files
fwrite(mtcars, "test_a")
fwrite(mtcars, "test_b")
fwrite(mtcars, "test_c")

files_map <- "~/Desktop" 

output <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(files, function(file) {
    dt <- data.table::fread(paste0(files_map, "/", file))
    list("number_of_cols" = ncol(dt), "number_of_rows" = nrow(dt), "name_of_file" = file)
    })
)
```

```
   number_of_cols number_of_rows name_of_file
1:             11             32       test_a
2:             11             32       test_b
3:             11             32       test_c
```

Comment: Upvote but I would use `file.path(files_map, file)` instead of `paste0`.

Comment: With the file.path() its works well. Thanks